# How to Rename tomcat7-instance-create's folder name

Tags: linux, tomcat7, createinstance

I have created tomcat instance using below command,

```
sudo tomcat7-instance-create -p 80XX -c 80XX myInstanceName
```

Its been created successfully and works fine. Now i want to change the instance name **myInstanceName** to **myNewInstanceName** for some differentiate purpose.

Is there possible way to achieve this task.

Answer (score 0):

We need to find in what directory created "myInstanceName":

```
find / -type d -name 'myInstanceName'
```

Rename folder:

```
mv /path/folder/myInstanceName /path/folder/myNewInstanceName
```

Edit sh scripts where `CATALINA_BASE="/path/folder/myInstanceName"`  to

```
CATALINA_BASE="/path/folder/myNewInstanceName"
```